# incorporate traffic signal waiting time into travel time using osmnx

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

ox.shortest_path allows me to find a route that minimizes travel time. However, the aggregate travel time as computed in this osmnx example (https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/main/notebooks/02-routing-speed-time.ipynb) only computes travel time on the edge, without considering waiting time in front of traffic lights:

```
# compare the two routes
route1_length = int(sum(ox.utils_graph.route_to_gdf(G, route1, "length")["length"]))
route2_length = int(sum(ox.utils_graph.route_to_gdf(G, route2, "length")["length"]))
route1_time = int(sum(ox.utils_graph.route_to_gdf(G, route1, "travel_time")["travel_time"]))
route2_time = int(sum(ox.utils_graph.route_to_gdf(G, route2, "travel_time")["travel_time"]))
print("Route 1 is", route1_length, "meters and takes", route1_time, "seconds.")
print("Route 2 is", route2_length, "meters and takes", route2_time, "seconds.")
```

The "highway" tag for nodes lists if there are traffic signals (i.e. "traffic_signals"). I think I can probably find out how many nodes on the route have traffic_signals, and maybe assume the wait time for each traffic signal is 20 seconds.

Are there better ways to estimate routing time while taking into account the waiting time in front of a signal?